# Android soft keyboard disappear when tap webView input field

Tags: android

I am working on the android WebView.When i tap the input field the soft keyboard open for a few seconds and disappear then automatically.

Answer (score 0):

in xml try this line might work

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```